# Makefile не могу запустить несколько команд последовательно

Tags: golang, makefile

Есть makefile в котором правила для запуска сервиса и образа в докере.
Почему-то отрабатывает только одно зависимое правило, например стартует сервис и управление не передается правилу которое должно стартовать запуск образа.
Правило: run: start-server start-docker  ## Запускает сервис.
Подскажите где я ошибаюсь?

```
.PHONY: run stop generate-proto run-tests start-docker stop-docker stop-server start-server

GO=go
PLATFORM_FILES="./CityEmploy/cmd/main.go"
PROTO_DIR="./protos/"
DOCKER_FILE="./docker-compose.yaml"

start-server:
    @echo Running CITY EMPLOY
    $(GO) run $(PLATFORM_FILES)
    
stop-server:
    @echo Stopping server CITY EMPLOY
    @for PID in $$(ps -ef | grep "[g]o run" | awk '{ print $$2 }'); do \
        echo stopping go $$PID; \
        kill $$PID; \
    done
    @for PID in $$(ps -ef | grep "[g]o-build" | awk '{ print $$2 }'); do \
        echo stopping CityEmploy $$PID; \
        kill $$PID; \
    done

start-docker: ## Запускает докер
    @echo Start docker
    docker-compose -f $(DOCKER_FILE) up

stop-docker: ## Стопает докер
    @echo Stop docker
    docker-compose -f $(DOCKER_FILE) down

run: start-server start-docker  ## Запускает сервис.

stop: stop-server stop-docker  ## Отсановка сервиса

generate-proto: ## Сгенерить grpc
    @echo Generate files
    protoc --go_out=$(PROTO_DIR) --go-grpc_out=$(PROTO_DIR) $(PROTO_DIR)*.proto
```

Comment: По умолчанию make запускает правила в один поток. Подозреваю что `go run` не завершается поэтому make ждёт и ничего больше не исполняет

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за наводку буду гуглить. Неудобно запускать 2 таски отдельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для параллельного выполнения команд в makefile, можно использовать ключ "-j". Который означает количество параллельных job-ов

```
run: command1 command2

command1:
    echo "Running command 1"
    sleep 5

command2:
    echo "Running command 2"
    sleep 5
```

выполните `make -j 2 run`

```
$ time make -j 2 run 
echo "Running command 1"
echo "Running command 2"
Running command 2
Running command 1
sleep 5
sleep 5
make -j 2 run  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 5.023 total
```

Answer (score 0):

make всегда ждёт завершения правила, чтобы определить, есть ли ошибка и нужно ли переходить к следующему правилу.

В правиле `start-server` процесс не завершается, соответственно не завершается и правило. Судя по вашему правилу `stop-server`, вы ожидаете выполения в фоне. Так и запускайте в фоне:

```
start-server:
    @echo Running CITY EMPLOY
    $(GO) run $(PLATFORM_FILES) &
```

Обратите внимание на `&` в конце команды.